# Is the set convex?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Is the set convex? $$L = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \begin{matrix}
8x_1+3x_2 \leq 72\\ 
-x_1+x_2 \leq 2\\ 
x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0
\end{matrix}\right\}$$

---

I'm afraid a task like that can be asked in our exam and I have no idea how this could be solved. On the internet, I couldn't find much info either. However I read that a set is convex if it has 2 points $a,b$ such that $p \cdot a +(1-p) \cdot b$, where $0 \leq p \leq 1$ is still in the set.

I tried this

$$8x_1+3x_2 = 8(p \cdot x_1 + (1-p) \cdot  x_1)+3(p \cdot x_2+(1-p) \cdot x_2) \leq 72$$

Because $p\geq 0$, $(1-p) \geq 0$ too.

And because of the other restrictions in the set $-x_1+x_2 \leq 2$ and $x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0$, there is no way the inequality can be greater than $72$, thus the set is convex?

I hope you can tell me if my solution is correct or how to do it correctly? It seems very chaotic but I cannot explain it better myself : /

Comment: Is the intersection of convex sets convex? You are just intersecting (affine) half-planes, hence the question is trivial. The worst that might happen is that such intersection is empty, but for sure it is convex.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio But where do I intersect here? I don't understand :(

Comment: The set of points $(x,y)$ such that $\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\text{blah}_1(x,y)&\leq& 0 \\ \text{blah}_2(x,y)&\leq& 0 \end{array}\right.$ is the intersection between the set of points such that $\text{blah}_1(x,y)\leq 0$ and the set of points such that $\text{blah}_2(x,y)\leq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Does that mean if I proved that the intersection of convex sets is convex, I show that this set here is convex as well?

Comment: Exactly. And about the intersection of convex sets being convex, you may use the following argument: $X$ is convex iff for any $x_1,x_2\in X$, the segment joining $x_1$ with $x_2$ belongs to $X$. We may declare empty sets convex by royal decree.